# How to use any() to test if two arrays overlap

Tags: python, numpy

I want to test if two arrays have common elements. I tried this but it does not work.

```
a = np.array([4,5])
b = np.array([1,-1])
a.any() in b
```

And this returns `True`...

Comment: Use `np.isin` or `np.in1d` alongwith it.

Comment: One simple, though strictly more expensive than necessary, approach would be to see if the intersection `np.intersect1d(a, b)` is empty or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `all` or `any` **depending on what's your goal**:

```
all(np.isin(a,b))
#or
#np.isin(a, b).all()
```

or

```
any(np.isin(a,b))
#or
#np.isin(a, b).any()
```

---

**Example using `all`:**

```
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([1,2])

all(np.isin(a,b))
#True
```

**Example using `any`:**

```
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([1,3])

any(np.isin(a,b))
#True
```

Comment: It's exactly the same thing as `all(np.isin(a,b))`